# How to retrieve elements from an array

Tags: python

I have an array -

```py
a = ['person', 'dog', 'fire hydrant']
```

How do I get the first element of this array - person and print it

Comment: To access the first element: `a[0]`. To print it: `print(a[0])`.

Comment: `print(a[0])` like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward.

do -

```py
print(a[0])
```

[0] takes the first element and prints it

Answer (score 1):

To access elements in an array, you can use their index.
Arrays start at index `0`.

So here, you would do

```py
a[0]
```

You can find more information on Python lists [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)